# How to dynamically adjust the size of a D3 rect based on the foreignObject's height

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How to dynamically adjust the size of a D3 rect based on the foreignObject's height. I am not sure how to get hold of the height of the foreignObject. I tried a lot of methods but none seem to work. I have been struggling with this for the past couple of day. It would be great if anyone can help me with this.

```js
function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function () {
    var text = d3.select(this),
      words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
      word,
      line = [],
      lineNumber = 0,
      lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
      y = text.attr('y'),
      x = text.attr('x')
    dy = parseFloat(text.attr('dy')),
      tspan = text
      .text(null)
      .append('tspan')
      .attr('x', x)
      .attr('y', y)
      .attr('dy', dy + 'em');
    while ((word = words.pop())) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(' '));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(' '));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text
          .append('tspan')
          .attr('x', x)
          .attr('y', y)
          .attr('dy', ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + 'em')
          .text(word);
      }
    }
  });
}

var svg = d3
  .select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', 500)
  .attr('height', 5000);

// var longText =
//   'This is very very long text. This is very very long text. This is very very long text. This is very very long text. This is very very long text. This is very very long text.';

// var longText =
//   '<span>hi</span>';

var longText = '<span> hello[&times;10<sup>-15</sup> ss<sup>-1</sup>]hello[&times;10<sup>-15</sup> ss<sup>-1</sup>]hello[&times;10<sup>-15</sup> ss<sup>-1</sup>]hello[&times;10<sup>-15</sup> ss<sup>-1</sup>]hello[&times;10<sup>-15</sup> ss<sup>-1</sup>]</span>';

var totHeight = 0;

drawRect();

function drawRect() {
  //var someWidth = randomIntFromInterval(40, 300);
  var someWidth = 212;

  var g = svg
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'foreignObjwrapper')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(20,' + totHeight + ')');

  var rect = g
    .append('rect')
    .style('fill', 'steelblue')
    .attr('x', 50)
    .attr('y', 50)
    .attr('width', someWidth)
    .attr('height', 100);

  const text = g
    .append('foreignObject')
    .attr('width', 200)
    .attr('height', 200)
    .attr('id', 'textBox')
    .attr('x', 50)
    .attr('y', 60)
    .attr('id', 'textBox')
    .style('fill', 'black')
    .append('xhtml:body')
    .html(longText);

  // var img = g.append('svg:image')
  //   .attr('x', 250)
  //   .attr('y', 40)
  //   .attr('width', 24)
  //   .attr('height', 24)
  //   .attr(
  //     'xlink:href',
  //     './img/edit-24-px.svg'
  //   );

  text.on('click', function () {
    var newText = '<span> bye[&times;10<sup>-15</sup> ss<sup>-1</sup>]</span>';
    //d3.append('text').html("<span> bye </span>");
    text.html(newText);
    console.log('hi', newText);
    //document.getElementsByClassName("textBox").innerHTML = newText;

  });

   //var height = text.node().getBBox().height + 25;
  // totHeight += height + 10;
  // rect.attr('height', height);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="body"></div>
```

Comment: Can you explain in a bit more detail what you want? You set the width and height of the `foreignObject` here, should we ignore that, for example?

Comment: so basically I have a D3 rect and to this I append text(in the form of foreignObject). I want to dynamically increase the height of the rect to accommodate all the contents of the foreignObject (in this case text). If you run the code snippet you will find that the text overflows out of the rect currently which I need to fix. As I am completely new to this I have just put  some initial width and height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just give the `body` a background instead:

```js
function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
      words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
      word,
      line = [],
      lineNumber = 0,
      lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
      y = text.attr('y'),
      x = text.attr('x')
    dy = parseFloat(text.attr('dy')),
      tspan = text
      .text(null)
      .append('tspan')
      .attr('x', x)
      .attr('y', y)
      .attr('dy', dy + 'em');
    while ((word = words.pop())) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(' '));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(' '));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text
          .append('tspan')
          .attr('x', x)
          .attr('y', y)
          .attr('dy', ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + 'em')
          .text(word);
      }
    }
  });
}

var svg = d3
  .select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', 500)
  .attr('height', 5000);

// var longText =
//   'This is very very long text. This is very very long text. This is very very long text. This is very very long text. This is very very long text. This is very very long text.';

// var longText =
//   '<span>hi</span>';

var longText = '<span> hello[&times;10<sup>-15</sup> ss<sup>-1</sup>]hello[&times;10<sup>-15</sup> ss<sup>-1</sup>]hello[&times;10<sup>-15</sup> ss<sup>-1</sup>]hello[&times;10<sup>-15</sup> ss<sup>-1</sup>]hello[&times;10<sup>-15</sup> ss<sup>-1</sup>]</span>';

var totHeight = 0;

drawRect();

function drawRect() {
  //var someWidth = randomIntFromInterval(40, 300);
  var someWidth = 212;

  var g = svg
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'foreignObjwrapper')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(20,' + totHeight + ')');

  const text = g
    .append('foreignObject')
    .attr('width', 200)
    .attr('height', 200)
    .attr('id', 'textBox')
    .attr('x', 50)
    .attr('y', 60)
    .append('xhtml:body')
    .style("background", "steelblue")
    .style("border", "dashed black 1px")
    .html(longText);

  // var img = g.append('svg:image')
  //   .attr('x', 250)
  //   .attr('y', 40)
  //   .attr('width', 24)
  //   .attr('height', 24)
  //   .attr(
  //     'xlink:href',
  //     './img/edit-24-px.svg'
  //   );

  text.on('click', function() {
    var newText = '<span> bye[&times;10<sup>-15</sup> ss<sup>-1</sup>]</span>';
    //d3.append('text').html("<span> bye </span>");
    text.html(newText);
    console.log('hi', newText);
    //document.getElementsByClassName("textBox").innerHTML = newText;

  });

  //var height = text.node().getBBox().height + 25;
  // totHeight += height + 10;
  // rect.attr('height', height);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="body"></div>
```

---

Alternatively you can get the height of the body using `text.node().clientHeight`:

```js
function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
      words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
      word,
      line = [],
      lineNumber = 0,
      lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
      y = text.attr('y'),
      x = text.attr('x')
    dy = parseFloat(text.attr('dy')),
      tspan = text
      .text(null)
      .append('tspan')
      .attr('x', x)
      .attr('y', y)
      .attr('dy', dy + 'em');
    while ((word = words.pop())) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(' '));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(' '));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text
          .append('tspan')
          .attr('x', x)
          .attr('y', y)
          .attr('dy', ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + 'em')
          .text(word);
      }
    }
  });
}

var svg = d3
  .select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', 500)
  .attr('height', 5000);

// var longText =
//   'This is very very long text. This is very very long text. This is very very long text. This is very very long text. This is very very long text. This is very very long text.';

// var longText =
//   '<span>hi</span>';

var longText = '<span> hello[&times;10<sup>-15</sup> ss<sup>-1</sup>]hello[&times;10<sup>-15</sup> ss<sup>-1</sup>]hello[&times;10<sup>-15</sup> ss<sup>-1</sup>]hello[&times;10<sup>-15</sup> ss<sup>-1</sup>]hello[&times;10<sup>-15</sup> ss<sup>-1</sup>]</span>';

var totHeight = 0;

drawRect();

function drawRect() {
  //var someWidth = randomIntFromInterval(40, 300);
  var someWidth = 212;

  var g = svg
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'foreignObjwrapper')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(20,' + totHeight + ')');

  const padding = 5;
  var rect = g
    .append('rect')
    .style('fill', 'steelblue')
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-dasharray", "5")
    .attr('x', 50)
    .attr('y', 60)
    .attr('width', someWidth + padding * 2);

  const text = g
    .append('foreignObject')
    .attr('width', someWidth)
    .attr('height', 200)
    .attr('id', 'textBox')
    .attr('x', 50 + padding)
    .attr('y', 60 + padding)
    .attr('id', 'textBox')
    .style('fill', 'black')
    .append('xhtml:body')
    .style("margin", 0)
    .html(longText);

  rect.attr("height", text.node().clientHeight + padding * 2);

  // var img = g.append('svg:image')
  //   .attr('x', 250)
  //   .attr('y', 40)
  //   .attr('width', 24)
  //   .attr('height', 24)
  //   .attr(
  //     'xlink:href',
  //     './img/edit-24-px.svg'
  //   );

  text.on('click', function() {
    var newText = '<span> bye[&times;10<sup>-15</sup> ss<sup>-1</sup>]</span>';
    //d3.append('text').html("<span> bye </span>");
    text.html(newText);
    console.log('hi', newText);
    //document.getElementsByClassName("textBox").innerHTML = newText;

  });

  //var height = text.node().getBBox().height + 25;
  // totHeight += height + 10;
  // rect.attr('height', height);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="body"></div>
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223449/discussion-between-ruben-helsloot-and-passionateabtcoding).